# Lasso select on amchart maps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, amcharts, amcharts4

G'day !!

I am trying to create a lasso map using am-charts,any leads or ideas will be of great help , looking for something like the below example :

http://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/498a150f94cd21e2270f

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Had to steer away from am-charts and used leaflets

Demo :https://moghthalkushal.github.io/leaflet-maps-with-lasso/#

Lasso Plugin Provider : "https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso"

amcharts says , they are not planning for any such things as of now :
https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2022

Comment: How to use it in R software? please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68342915/use-lasso-instead-rectangle-for-select-reign-in-leaflet